# updating the array that is being passed to highcharts in meteor app

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, highcharts

I'm using meteor to build a dashboard that uses highcharts to build the charts. Current set up is as follows. The page loads to show a drop down menu. When the user clicks the drop down menu, the client.js queries the database based on the selection, pushes the results to a few global arrays followed by a blaze.render of the template which has the chart. The chart uses the global variables as the series data and the xAxis categories. Problem is that when the user selects a different option from the drop down, the arrays should get updated and the chart re-rendered. But I noticed that the array does not get populated with new values. Instead new values get appended to the array.

Code below:

```
  Template.districtDropdown.events({
'change #selectDistrict' : function(event, template){
  // productValues2.length = 0;
  // productUsage2.length = 0;
  // productFidelity2.length = 0;
  // productNames2.length = 0;
  event.preventDefault();
  var selectedValue = template.$("#selectDistrict").val();
  console.log("You Selected " + selectedValue);
  var filter = {
    find: {
      'School District' : selectedValue
    }
  };

  $(filter).ready(function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('aggByDistrict', filter, function() {
      productUsage2 = [], productValues2 = [], productFidelity2 = [];
      productNames2 = _.uniq(CombinedData.find().map( function(doc) { return doc.Product; }));
      for(var i = 0; i < productNames2.length; i++) {
        productValues2.push(CombinedData.find({'Product' : productNames2[i]}).count());
        productUsage2.push(CombinedData.find({'Product' : productNames2[i], 'Usage' : {$gt:0}}).count());
        productFidelity2.push(CombinedData.find({'Product' : productNames2[i], 'Fidelity' :1 }).count());
      };
      console.log(productNames2, productUsage2, productValues2, productFidelity2);
      // Renders the highchart that shows the various aggs for selected district
      Blaze.render(Template.LicensesDistributedByDistrict, $("#LicensesByDistrictCharts")[0]);
    });
  });
}
  });
```

If I were to uncomment the productValues2.length = 0 then the chart gets empty arrays.

I know this is probably a a horrible implementation, but I'm trying to learn how to use meteor / highcharts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I think I figured out the answer. With the code posted by me earlier, the client side minimongo is populated by the subscribe command when the client makes the first choice from the drop down menu. When the client makes a second choice from the drop down, the server uses the new filter, and published the new documents to the already live collection on the client side minimongodb. To fix this, I modified the code by adding a .stop() at the end, after the chart has been rendered. This stops / clears the client side collection, and the whole process starts again when the client selects a second option from the drop down. Fixed code below:

```
  //Handle the selection event from district dropdowns
  Template.districtDropdown.events({
    'change #selectDistrict' : function(event, template){
      event.preventDefault();
      var selectedValue = $(event.target).val();
      var filter = {
        find: {
          'School District' : selectedValue
        }
      };

      // console.log(filter);
      $(filter).ready(function() {
        var filteredCollection = Meteor.subscribe('aggByDistrict', filter, function() {
          productNames2 = [], productUsage2 = [], productValues2 = [], productFidelity2 = [];
          console.log(productNames2, productUsage2, productValues2, productFidelity2);
          productNames2.length = 0, productUsage2.length = 0, productValues2.length = 0, productFidelity2 .length = 0;
              productNames2 = _.uniq(CombinedData.find().map( function(doc) { return doc.Product; }));
              for(var i = 0; i < productNames2.length; i++) {
                // productValues2 = CombinedData.find({'Product' : productNames2[i]}).map()
                productValues2.push(CombinedData.find({'Product' : productNames2[i]}).count());
                productUsage2.push(CombinedData.find({'Product' : productNames2[i], 'Usage' : {$gt:0}}).count());
                productFidelity2.push(CombinedData.find({'Product' : productNames2[i], 'Fidelity' :1 }).count());
              };
              console.log(productNames2, productUsage2, productValues2, productFidelity2);
              // Renders the highchart that shows the various aggs for selected district
              Blaze.render(Template.LicensesDistributedByDistrict, $("#LicensesByDistrictCharts")[0]);
              filteredCollection.stop();
            });
          });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

It's appending the values because you're not clearing out its existing values.

`// productValues2.length = 0;
// productUsage2.length = 0;
// productFidelity2.length = 0;
// productNames2.length = 0;`

The code above clears the arrays

Comment: I thought so too, and that's why I had those in. But those did not help, which is why I commented them out. Un-commenting those didn't change the values that highcharts shows.

Comment: with those commented the values are still being appended? what effect did it have when you un-commented them?

Comment: Okay, after a few console.logs I figured that the arrays do get emptied out by the productValues2.length = 0; statements. I think there is some issue on the server side.

Lets say I choose Option 1 from drop down, I get values 2000, 2000, 15
When I choose Option 2 from the drop down, I get values 2033, 2033, 18

Instead, were I to refresh the page, and select the option 2 directly, I get the actual values which are 33, 33 and 3.